# Do the equations on this piece of art have physical significance

Tags: soft-question, field-theory

Someone I know owns a piece of art, which is shown in the figure.

[image]

$$[\varphi_\alpha(x), \varphi_\beta(y)]= -i\Delta_{\alpha\beta}(x-y)$$

and

$$U[\sigma,\sigma_0]= I-i\int_{\sigma_0}^\sigma\mathcal{H}'(x')U[\sigma',\sigma_0]\,\mathrm dx'\,. $$

I have some theories on what the physical significance (or lack there of) of the particular symbols are, but would like to see if meaning jumps out at anyone.

(If this is completely out of place on the Stack Exchange, let me know, as this is meant to be a light-hearted question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In quantum field theory bosonic fields $\varphi_\alpha\left(x\right)$ satisfy $\left[\varphi_\alpha\left(x\right),\,\varphi_\beta\left(y\right)\right]=0$, unless noncommutative geometry is incorporated in which case we achieve the moral general case in the first equation you've asked about. This is analogous to the fact that discrete quantum mechanics satisfies $\left[x_i,\,x_j\right]=0$ without noncommutative geometry, or $\left[x_i,\,x_j\right]=-i\Delta_{ij}$ with it. Note that each $\Delta$ is antisymmetric; the $-i$ is there so the entries of $\Delta$ will be real.

The second equation is equivalent to the conditions $$U\left[\sigma_0,\,\sigma_0\right]=I,\,\frac{\partial U\left[\sigma,\,\sigma_0\right]}{\partial \sigma}=-i\mathcal{H}\left[\sigma,\,\sigma_0\right]U\left[\sigma,\,\sigma_0\right],$$which characterise unitary transformations between states with parameters $\sigma_0,\,\sigma$ for some dimensionless function $\mathcal{H}$ along the path. A gradual increase in the state's parameter during a gradual unitary evolution is depicted in the diagram.

Comment: you are right that the equations do have similar form to those in QFT.. however whats perplexing to me is the lines do look more like streamlined flow rather than QFT..i get your reason, but it would have been better if the artist would have stuck to Feynman diagrams :P

Comment: @BruceLee The equation I interpreted as a QFT commutator could have another meaning, such as Poisson brackets in a noncommutative geometry. That might be closer to the example that you're thinking of. As for streamlined flow, what I saw was a time-evolution of an unspecified system, e.g. transition between the Cauchy surfaces of a globally hyperbolic spacetime.

Comment: Great, thanks. I was thinking more along the lines of the poisson bracket. But, of course, the interpretation of the art is open to personal perspective.